# Does `cargo install` download binaries compiled on someone else's computer?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Does `cargo install` download binaries compiled on someone else's computer?
Can it be the case that such pre-builts are sometimes downloaded when executing `cargo install`?
The output of `cargo install` suggests that compiling takes place, but I am not sure if I can rely that `cargo install` will never download anything pre-compiled to my computer.
Thus, whenever I can I manually clone a repo and compile the binaries myself, .e.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/mitnk/cicada.git && cd cicada && cargo build --release && sudo mv target/release/cicada /usr/local/bin
```

instead of installing, e.g. `cargo install -f cicada`. I only do the former because I would like to avoid downloading
binaries compiled on someone else's copmputer? Another reason for this is that I prefer to compile the binaries with `--release`.
I am not quite sure that such optimization takes place when `cargo install` is executed.

Comment: No, it downloads the source and builds it locally. And it passes the `--release` flag by default. Look at `cargo help install`, it's all written out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cargo install` downloads and compiles the crate locally, using the same mechanisms as when it builds a crate you have downloaded.

`cargo install` defaults to release builds. You have to use the `--debug` flag to build debug builds.

The build scripts of the crates may download pre-compiled binaries. For example, crates that are bindings to C libraries may download the library. But this is true even if you `git clone` the source as well.